# How to get element from JSON array in array in array

Tags: arrays, json, typescript, nativescript

I have a question about this JSON. How to get coordinates from here?

I try to use `for(){}` like code below but doesn't work.

```
   item {
        "type": "type1",
        "features": [{
                "type": "typeee1",
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        -19.726330999999998,
                        41.360610000000001
                    ]},
                "properties": {
                    "id_strada": "1433",
                    "nome_strada": "test3",
                } },
            {
                "type": "typeee2",
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        19.726344999999998,
                        26.36063
                    ] },
                "properties": {
                   id_strada": "13",
                   "nome_strada": "test5",
                } },
            {
                "type": "typeee3",
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        19.726358999999999,
                        98.36065
                    ] },
                "properties": {
                  id_strada": "14",
                    "nome_strada": "test34",
                } }, {
                "type": "typeee5",
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        19.726372999999999,
                        55.360669999999999
                    ] },
                "properties": {
                    id_strada": "14335",
                    "nome_strada": "test39",
                } }],
        "last_update": "15-08-2019 15:04:45"
    }
```

function that call JSON is like below.

```
item: Item[];
        this.ws.getitems().subscribe(
                item => {
                    this.item = item;
                    console.log('this.item.length', this.item.length)
                    for (let i = 0; i < this.item.length; i++) {        
                    }
                }
            );
```

> this.item.length is undefined

My question is, how to get coordinates in here?

Can you ask me any idea please?
Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't you want `item.features.length`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: Your javascript object is broken - missing `"` and extra `,` all over the place

Comment: You can test your JSON here: https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=66ee841768174690807ed68c2c15cf93

Comment: It is also not clear what you want. You say "get coordinates" - but there are lots of coordinates. Do you want an array of arrays? DO you want an object with one of the values as the key and the associated coordinates as the value?

Comment: @JanneckLange https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=66ee841768174690807ed68c2c15cf93

Comment: @HereticMonkey I change `for (let i = 0; i < this.item.features.length; i++) {console.log(this.item.features[i])}` in this console I get `{ "type": "type1", "features": [{ "type": "typeee1","geometry": { "type": "Point","coordinates": [ -19.726330999999998,41.360610000000001]}, "properties": { "id_strada": "1433",  "nome_strada": "test3" } }` Now how to get coordinates please?

Comment: Please, read the linked duplicate. It has an exhaustive answer showing how to figure this out for yourself. Me spoon-feeding you the answer isn't going to help you in your next assignment, or the one after that. Look at the patterns of how your current answers are attempting to answer your question with the incomplete information you've given, and apply it to the actual data you are getting.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thank you, but I need help, for this I write my code problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have an array in an array in an array. You have an array in an object in an object in an array in an object.

```js
interface Feature {
  type: string;
  geometry: {
    type: string;
    coordinates: [ number, number ];
  };
  properties: {
    id_strada: string;
    nome_strada: string;
  };
}

interface Item {
  type: string;
  features: Feature[];
  last_update: string;
}

const items$: Observable<Item> = this.ws.getItems();
const coordinates$: Observable<[number, number]> = items$.pipe(
  switchMap((item: Item) => of(
    ...item.features.map((feature: Feature) => feature.geometry.coordinates)
  )),
);

coordinates$.subscribe((coordinates: [number, number]) => console.log(coordinates));
```

It is really unclear exactly what your intention is here. Your `Item` object has multiple coordinates within it. Do you intend to link all of the coordinates, or just the first, or do you want to split them by feature? I've provided you a way to just have an unlinked stream of all coordinates you ever receive. You'll have to figure out what it is you want to do with that.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I can't get coordinates like you say. How to continue when I subscribe item `this.item = item;`

Comment: I do not know what your contract of `ws.getItems` is, so I provided you with a snippet that operates directly on the example JSON you provided. Just the method signature of `ws.getItems()` would probably be enough for a more accurate solution for you.

Comment: `.pipe(map((response: HttpResponse<any>) => {
            return response.body;
        }`  This response.body is item

Comment: I change for (let i = 0; i < this.item.features.length; i++) {console.log(this.item.features[i])} in this console I get { "type": "type1", "features": [{ "type": "typeee1","geometry": { "type": "Point","coordinates": [ -19.726330999999998,41.360610000000001]}, "properties": { "id_strada": "1433", "nome_strada": "test3" } } Now how to get coordinates please?

Answer (score 0):

If you were already in `item`, coordinates are at `item.geometry.coordinates`

If your supplied json was `x`, you could get the first coordinates at `x.features[0].geometry.coordinates`.

You could find each set of coordinates with:

```
x.features.forEach(item => {
  let coords = item.geometry.coordinates
  // do something with coords
})
```

Comment: I am in item, I can get coordinates like you say. I have this Model `export class Spots {
    type : string;
    geometry:Geometry[];
    properties: Properties[];
    features: string;
    coordinates : string;
      constructor(obj: any) {
        this.type = obj && obj.type;
        this.geometry = obj && obj.geometry;
        this.properties = obj && obj.properties;
        this.features = obj && obj.features;
        this.coordinates = obj && obj.coordinates;
      }
    }`

Comment: I change for (let i = 0; i < this.item.features.length; i++) {console.log(this.item.features[i])} in this console I get { "type": "type1", "features": [{ "type": "typeee1","geometry": { "type": "Point","coordinates": [ -19.726330999999998,41.360610000000001]}, "properties": { "id_strada": "1433", "nome_strada": "test3" } } Now how to get coordinates please?